# WinForm datagrid event on sorting procedure complete

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

Is there in Windows form an event for DataGridView element that starts after a column header is clicked and sorting is complete?

I try `ColumnSortModeChanged` and `ColumnSortModeChangedbut` they doesn't start.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`DataGridView.Sorted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sorted?view=netframework-4.7.2) event.